# Sencha Cmd version is incompatible with required version

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I download the latest ExtJs version which is 7.3.1.27, but when i download the latest CMD, it's 7.3.0.19.

When I try to generate app, then it says " Sencha Cmd version (7.3.0.19) is incompatible with required version (7.3.0.20-7.3.0.20)"

Do we really need to match until the smallest version number?
Why can't it support up to major version?
Or Why don't make the CMD and ExtJS version same for download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the root of your projetc and run the command :

```
sencha workspace upgrade
```

If you get errors then edit sencha.cfg of your application accordingly to the required version of both Sencha Cmd and Ext JS.
After edit run the command again

Answer (score 0):

The same issue:

```
[ERR] Sencha Cmd version (7.5.1.20) is incompatible with required version (7.6.0.33-7.6.0.33)
```

Sencha Cmd 7.5.1.20 for now is last version but why do it required upper version?
I wasted a lot of time to find out this issue.
**My solution:**

- Go to `/Users/{your name}/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.5.1.20/`
- Open file `sencha.cfg`
- Write your required version in this line `cmd.version=7.6.0.33`

After this manipulation sencha generate app works fine